# find all primes $p$ such that $a^p-1$ has a primitive factor.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

We say that *a prime $q$ is a primitive factor* of $a^n-1$ if $q|a^n-1$, but $q$ does not divide $a^m-1$ for any $m$ such that $0<m<n$. Given $a\ge2$, find all primes $p$ such that $a^p-1$ has a primitive factor.

Comment: Found. Now what?

Comment: find the primes p @barakmanos

Comment: OK, found them. Now what?

Comment: Write them here. How many primes are there? @barakmanos

Comment: You show me yours and I'll show you mine... It's a different way of saying: Please show your thoughts, attempts, progress and general effort made towards finding the solution yourself. Don't just publish a question, or a list of instructions like "find" (BTW, you didn't even say "please", but even "please find" is not good enough in this case).

Comment: I am so sorry you are right! Could you please help me to approach this question? @barakmanos

Comment: As I mentioned in the comment above, please show your thoughts, attempts, progress and general effort made towards finding the solution yourself.

Comment: The problem is that I have no concrete idea. @barakmanos

Comment: Please it is important to know the solution of this question. I would appreciate it if you could help. @barakmanos

Comment: I was looking at the discussion and I was thinking that we should be concerned for the questions more. As for the question I am sorry but I don't have a concrete idea either. So @barakmanos it is to you :)